# Chrome 72.0.3626.109 unable to parse axios response

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, cors, axios

I ran into a weired problem recently and i can't figure out why it's happening, i'm using `axios` to send a `POST` to a backend, it used to work fine, but after updating to `72.0.3626.109` Chrome is unable to parse the `data` that contains the error message, but Firefox , Postman and NodeJs are able to do so,

when using `fetch` it's the same but i get an error (just  in chrome ) saying `unexpected end of json`.

why Chrome isn't able to parse the response ?

On a side note : i'm using the CORS extension in both browsers.

this is the function i'm using :

```
(async () => {

  const result = await axios({
    method : "POST",
    url : "https://preprod.../user/signup",
    headers : {
      "Application-ID": "t1OLua...ukeqg",
      Authorization: "Bearer null"    
    },
    data : { email: "marial...@gmail.com", uuid: null },
    timeout: 3000
  }).catch(e => {
    return e.response;
  });

  console.log(result);

})();
```

**EDIT :**

try the same function above with this url : https://www.mocky.io/v2/5c6b23f7330000e33c7f4eba

**Chrome : (data : "")**

[image]

**Firefox : (data : {foo: "bar" })**
[image]

Comment: Do you have a way of checking the exact JSON string returned by the server? Perhaps it is slightly malformed, Firefox might be more forgiving to the issue.

Comment: Another possibility is that the servers content-length header does not match the actual length of JSON it is sending. Either way, I would be looking at the server

Comment: @JyeLewis i asked the backend team to send me the stringified `JSON` and it's exactly what Firefox is showing

Comment: @JyeLewis i updated the question with a verifiable url.

Comment: The response from `http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c6b23f7330000e33c7f4eba` is 403 Forbidden when I try to test the code snippet in the question with that URL.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thnx for looking at it, try `https` , here's the behaviour i'm having : https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-6e38ae80f7c4.gif

Comment: What is that CORS extension you're running? Does the same happen still if you disable the extension?

Comment: @maxpaj i'm using this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en , and the behaviour when enabled / disabled is http://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-6e38ae80f7c4.gif

Comment: I can't see that image, it gives me a 404 and I believe that's not the picture you want to show.

Comment: In any case, you should take a look at the network tab in Chrome developer tools to see if the response from the server even contains any JSON data. Alos, I think you should exclude axios or fetch from the equation.

Comment: @maxpaj sorry for the broken link, i guess it expired, https://imgur.com/a/q1o13Vk , yeah after some debugging, i guess it's a cors thing, when disabled, there's no response in the network Tab.